# Why is `git clean -xfdn` threatening to remove ~/?

Tags: git

When switching between branches with significant differences between them, Xcode can get quite upset/confused (probably due to unversioned contents of `xcuserdata`).

I find that can be solved by ensuring my working copy is in a clean state:

```
git clean -xfd
```

To be confident of not unintentionally losing anything, a dry-run is a good idea:

```
git clean -xfdn
```

Right now, the alarming final line of output from the dry-run is:

```
Would remove ~/
```

The root of my working copy is a long way from my home directory. I can find no symlinks "reaching" out from my working copy to `~`.

In this context, does git mean something *else* by `~/`?

Why, from a working copy 5 directories deep, might it think `~/` needs deleting?

Comment: Does anything related to `~/` show up in `git status`?

Comment: BTW for safety I would use `-xdn`, not `-xfdn`. The `n` cancels the `f` but if you forget to type `n` or accidentally hit backspace you're in trouble.

Comment: Right now `git status` is only reporting one (expected) un-tracked file.

Comment: What is the output of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`?

Comment: That outputs the full path to the working copy. (i.e. identical to what `pwd` reports)

Comment: "Xcode can get quite upset/confused" This is not what you asked (and I can't answer the question you did ask), but my solution to that is: close the project; make the branch switch; open the project, and immediately clean the build folder. In very extreme circumstances I have to quit Xcode, throw away the DerivedData folder, make the branch switch. I have to say I think your solution is way too extreme; blowing away your userdata and xcworkspace is a really bad idea.

Comment: Okay, and just to make sure, if you go to your home directory and type `git status`, the output is "not a git repository"?

Comment: That Is correct @mkrieger1

Comment: I do generally try to do that @matt, but on this occasion I forgot. Included it here as "back story".

Comment: And if you remove the `x` or use `X` instead, does it still say "would remove ~/"?

Comment: Also I think your hypothesis that Xcode's problem is "probably due to unversioned contents of xcuserdata" is just wrong; if it is (correctly) unversioned, nothing happens to it when you switch branches. The problem is Xcode's caching.

Comment: "but on this occasion I forgot" Sure, I forget all the time too, but you can always recover. Usually I get the spinning beachball, I force quit, and _then_ I blow away the derived data. :) If you get the thing about which version of the current file to use, ask for the one on disk.

Comment: `git clean -dn` does not mention `~/`

Comment: I've had more subtle oddities, like the navigator still showing files/sub-projects from the previous branch (I want to say even after removing derived data and a quit and re-launch). The vast majority (but not absolutely 100%) of what `git clean` removes is `xcuserdata`, hence them being my chief suspect. But as you say, that's not the problem we're trying to solve here.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this means that Git considers `~/` to be "ignored". Does it appear in `git status --ignored`?

Comment: `git clean -Xdn` does mention `~/`

Comment: `git status --ignored` does too

Comment: I did `git update-index --skip-worktree someGeneratedFile.json` yesterday, but reverted it shortly afterwards as it wasn't the correct solution (`git update-index --no-skip-worktree someGeneratedFile.json`)

Comment: Now you can pick one file from `~` and run `git check-ignore -v <path>` to find out why it is ignored.

Comment: Okay, with `update-index` involved I'm not sure how this affects everything.

Comment: From inside my working directory, `git check-ignore -v ~/someRealFile` reports `fatal: /full/path/to/someRealFile is outside repository`

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @mkrieger1. Maybe I should just abandon this working copy and do a fresh clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Git *lists* files (from `git clean`, or `git ls-files`, or other such commands), it never uses the `~/` user's-home-directory compression syntax.  So if `git clean -n -d other-flags-if/as-desired-here` says "Would remove ~/", it means Git thinks there is a *directory* named `~` living in the current directory, and Git would remove it:

```
$ git clean -nd
Would remove Syntax.md
$ mkdir \~
$ git clean -nd
Would remove Syntax.md
Would remove ~/
```

Note that I had to use `\~` when *making* this directory.  I could also have used `'~'` or similar: it's the *shell* that expands `~` here.  Git does have its own code to *expand* `~` so that you can refer to `~/.config/git-foo` files in `includeIf` directives, for instance, but this code is applied somewhat inconsistently (basically, "wherever it should be" and not "wherever it shouldn't be", with should / should-not being a judgment call).<sup>1</sup>

You probably did not make a directory named `~`, but something else apparently did.

---

<sup>1</sup>Because `~` expansion is performed by individual programs, and each one has its own rules about when and how `~` expansion occurs, we can get in a lot of trouble.  The same applies to variables like `$HOME` and `$USER`.  One of the niceties in original Unix, that has long since been lost, is that with the *shell* being the *only* place that does these special tricks, one had only to learn one set of rules about when such expansions took place, and how to prevent them.  Now that so many programs take it upon themselves to do their own globbing, with each program having its own rules, it's quite a mess.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, thanks - I'll check it on Monday (works machine)

Comment: Confirmed. Looking at the contents of that directory, it’s existence is down to a clumsily invoked invocation of xcodebuild / tee.